# Display translation on a component in Vuejs

Tags: vuejs2, localization, vue-i18n

I want to show a translation on the title of a component.
Here is the HTML code:

```html
   <user-card
      :totalUser="totalUsers"
      color="primary"
      icon="UserIcon"
      user-title="Total users"
  />
```

On my `user-card` component I have this:

```html
  <b-card class="text-center">
    <b-avatar
        :variant="`light-${color}`"
        class="mb-1"
        size="45"
    >
      <feather-icon
          :icon="icon"
          size="21"
      />
    </b-avatar>
    <div class="truncate">
      <h2 class="mb-25 font-weight-bolder">
        {{ totalUser}}
      </h2>
      <span>{{ user-title }}</span>
    </div>
  </b-card>
```

And to use translation I have this syntax where I get the translated terms from the JSON file:

```js
{{$t("Total users")}}
```

How can I implement this on the `user-title`?

Comment: what's {{$t("Total users")}} ? inshort what is $t

Comment: @MohsinAmjad its the function for translation provided by Vue I18n.

Comment: is $t accessible in `this` context as this.$t in your script ?

Comment: you mean to say like this ?

```user-title="$this.$t("Total users")"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this, I have tried to replicate your scenario in code sandbox.

[sample app](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-i18n-example-forked-ecn0h?file=/App.vue)

What you are doing wrong is that $t is a function that accepts variable name which has an actual message in it, first you have to define a variable e.g totalUserTitle: 'Total users' for multiple languages like I did in index.js, and then you can use it as `$t(totalUserTitle)`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`v-bind`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) and pass the expression to your `user-card` component directly:

```html
<user-card
    ...
    :user-title="$t('Total users')"
/>
```

You're actually already using this syntax in multiple places, this directive just tells Vue to "dynamically bind one or more attributes, or a component prop to an expression", which is exactly what you're looking for here.

This will evaluate `$t('Total users')` as an expression and then pass the result to your component as a prop.